# Wedderburn decomposition of commutative finite dimensional algebras via GAP

Tags: representation-theory, gap

Let $R$ be a commutative finite dimensional $K$-algebra over a field $K$ (for example the monoid ring of a a finite monoid over a field).
Assume we have $R$ in GAP. Then we can check whether $R$ is semisimple using the command RadicalOfAlgebra(R). When the value is 0, $R$ is semisimple.
Thus $R$ can be written as a finite product of finite field extensions of $K$.

> Question: Can we obtain those finite field extensions of $K$ or at least their number and $K$-dimensions using GAP?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working over a finite field, and can represent the algebra through matrices, you could try to split the regular module into its homogeneous components. This can be done with the GAP command `MTX.Indecomposition`. You then take a simple submodule in this component (try a spin of a random vector), and take the action of the homogeneous component on this module (and should let you deduce the appropriate field extension).

(If you add an example, I can try to show the corresponding GAP commands.)